# Render items in separated placeholder

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc

I'm trying to create a carousel and I want it to be *configurable* from the Experience Editor. By *configurable* I meant that it's possible to edit the image, text AND add/or remove slides.

The first time I create the carousel I can add/remove slides but no after saving it and opening it again, after rendering the carousel I can't remove just one slide because they all are part of the same placeholder (I can continue adding new slides and removing the new ones but not the old ones).

I have Carousel.cshtml and CarouselSlide.cshtml and the code look like:

Carousel.cshtml

```
<div class="carousel">
    @foreach (Item slide in Model.Item.Children)
    {
        @Html.Action("CarouselSlide", "MediaFeature", new { model = slide });
    }

    @Html.Sitecore().DynamicPlaceholder("slides")

</div>
```

CarouselSlide.cshtml

```
<div class="carousel-slide">
    <div class="carousel-slide-content">
        @Html.Sitecore().BeginField(....)
             <div class="background-image">
                  .....
             </div>

             <div class="text-container">
                  ....
             </div>
        @Html.Sitecore().EndField()
    </div>
</div>
```

So far, the issue looks like is related with the placeholders. Any ideas about how to render DynamicPlaceholders?

**EDIT**

"slides" placeholder is configured to allow only CarouselSlide components

Comment: Are you adding a slide component to the slides placeholder one by one? Or do you have a slides data template where the user is selecting slides to add to a slides container item and you select the slides container item as a datasource from your carousel component?

Comment: @dnstommy I'm adding them one by one from the Experience Editor

Comment: ok. Have you checked here for the doco on dynamic placeholders. Your placeholders should have guids at the end of them. https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/I/Integrated_Dynamic_Placeholders.aspx

Comment: I'm using http://fortis.ws/fortis-collection/dynamic-placeholders/ and my issues is not rendering one DynamicPlaceholder, the issue is when I need to render a list of items

Answer (score 0):

Remove the foreach loop.  It is unnecessary.  When Sitecore renders the placeholder it renders the previously added slides for you.  When in edit mode, it also renders the container that allows you to add additional components.

Using a dynamic placeholder as you have will allow you to have multiple Carousel components on a page.  Or more precisely, multiple components containing a placeholder with the key "slides".  It is most likely not causing the problems you are seeing with your slides.

**Update - additional info requested by OP**

It looks like what you have done is mix two different styles of development.  In one, you are explicitly rendering the children of the carousel item as slides.  In the second you are relying on Sitecore's presentation engine to dynamically render components into a placeholder that could be using data sources from somewhere else in the tree.  You need to pick one or the other, but **the second approach is generally preferred**.

To use the second approach, you would simply remove the foreach loop so that your Carousel view looks like this:

```
<div class="carousel">
    @Html.Sitecore().DynamicPlaceholder("slides")
</div>
```

If you decide to go with the first approach, you would remove the placeholder and then add Custom Experience Buttons to allow you to insert and sort child items under your carousel item.

With either approach, you may find that page editor does not play all that well with your Carousel javascript.  The most common workaround to this problem is to render the carousel as a flat list in page editor mode.

Comment: The foreach loop is used when I need to render existing slides. 
E.g.: I have created a carousel in the homepage and I want to re-use this carousel (including the slides of course) in another page, so I need a loop to render the existing slides

Comment: You don't need to do that.  The placeholder does it for you.

Comment: I don't catch your point, can you please update your answer with how the code should look like. I think what you say works only if i was not rendering a list of item (slides) but only one item in a specific placeholder